# For what purpose catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release command is used?

Tags: ros, catkin-make, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When to use or what is the purpose of `catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` command? How it differs from `catkin_make` command. Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295187/for-what-purpose-catkin_make--dcmake_build_type=release-command-is-used?/) by [malgudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29206/malgudi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2018-06-24

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-25**:
This is a direct duplicate of at least #q294789, which was asked 4 days ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` variable is used to specify a build type. Typically, the selected option (by default empty, but it can be `Release`, `Debug`, or some others) is used to figure out what options to use/flags to set when cmake actually calls the compiler.

In short, `Release` tells the compiler to do optimization and omit debug information that `Debug` would tell it to keep. I've seen some people recommend using `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` for better performance.

Calling `catkin_make` (and not specifying a value for `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`) results in something similar to using the `Debug` value.

See:
https://codeyarns.com/2015/05/14/build-types-in-cmake/
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html

---

Originally posted by [christophebedard](https://answers.ros.org/users/29634/christophebedard/) with karma: 641 on 2018-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Widmaier](https://answers.ros.org/users/28762/felix-widmaier/) on 2018-10-17**:
+1 to use `Release` for better performance. It depends on the source how much the gain is but I had cases where a release build was running around 100 times faster than a debug build. So as a rule of thumb: Always use `Release` except when debug symbols are explicitly needed.